# unmet dependencies error while installing tensorrt 5.1.5 on ec2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I am trying to install Tensorrt GA 5.1.5 from the nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1604-cuda10.0-trt5.1.5.0-ga-20190427_1-1_amd64.deb file on an EC2 instance. I have the following configuration
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Tensorflow 1.14
- Python 3.6
- CUDA 10
- CuDNN 7.5.1

I also face this error while executing the following command

```
~/software1$ sudo apt-get install tensorrt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tensorrt : Depends: libnvinfer5 (= 5.1.5-1+cuda10.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnvinfer-dev (= 5.1.5-1+cuda10.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnvinfer-samples (>= 5.1.0-1+cuda10.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnvinfer-samples (<= 5.2.0-1+cuda10.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

When I try an installation with the tar file (TensorRT-5.1.5.0.Ubuntu-16.04.5.x86_64-gnu.cuda-10.0.cudnn7.5.tar.gz),

I get the error file  tensorrt-5.1.5.0-cp36-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

How do I resolve this error? I am following the official documentation for [TensorRT 5.1.5](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-archived/tensorrt-515/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html)

Comment: Hi, can you post the output of: `sudo apt install -f`